# Send variable as ajax response

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm posting a form by ajax and printing response in the form page.

**Index.php:**

```
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.form.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
    function a(){alert('ok');
$(function(){ 
    $('#submitForm').ajaxForm(function(result){
                    alert('the form was successfully posted!');
                    document.getElementById('resulte').innerHTML=result;
                }).submit();
         });
         }
</script>
    <body>
    <form id="submitForm" name="submitForm" action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
    File: <input name="myfile" type="file" />
    <input type="button" id="submitBtn" name="submitBtn" value="Upload" onclick="a();" />
    </form>
    <div id="resulte" name="resulte">a</div>
    <span id="usererr" name="usererr" class="formerror"></span>
    <span id="passerr" name="passerr" class="formerror"></span>
    <span id="passconferr" name="passconferr" class="formerror"></span>
    </body>
```

**upload.php:**

```
<?php 
$result = 0; 
$target_path = 'uploads/' . basename( $_FILES['myfile']['name']); 
if(@move_uploaded_file($_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
$result = 1;
} 
sleep(1);
echo"good";
$arr=array('username'=>array('isEmpty'=>'required','exists'=>'username exists'),'password'=>array('isEmpty'=>'required'))
?>
```

I want to send $arr to ‘index.php’ by ajax and show the values in ‘usererr’ and ‘passerr’ spans

**OR**

echo each line in different spans in ‘index.php’. How can I do that ?

-thanks.

***Edit:***

I did the following but now no text is printing there in ‘usererr’ span and the alert box not displaying.whats wrong did I do ? (form is posted and file saved successfully, but the problem is about 'response')

**Index.php:**

```
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.form.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
function a(){ 
    $('#submitForm').ajaxForm({
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(result){        
                    alert('the form was successfully posted!');
              $('#usererr').html(result['username']['isEmpty']);
                }}).submit();
         }</script>

    <body>
    <form id="submitForm" name="submitForm" action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
    File: <input name="myfile" type="file" />
    <input type="button" id="submitBtn" name="submitBtn" value="Upload" onclick="a();" />
    </form>
    <div id="resulte" name="resulte">a</div>
    <span id="usererr" name="usererr" class="formerror"></span>
    <span id="passerr" name="passerr" class="formerror"></span>
    <span id="passconferr" name="passconferr" class="formerror"></span>
    </body>
```

**upload.php:**

```
<?php 
$result = 0; 
$target_path = 'uploads/' . basename( $_FILES['myfile']['name']); 
if(@move_uploaded_file($_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
$result = 1;
}
$arr=array('username'=>array('isEmpty'=>'required','exists'=>'username exists'),'password'=>array('isEmpty'=>'required'));
echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

Comment: It's not a good practice to put `sleep()` in your code.

Comment: thats for a file upload animation.the code is not completed yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use json as `dataType`, like:

```
$('#submitForm').ajaxForm({
   dataType: 'json',
   success: function(result){
       //get the required values from result like result.username.isEmpty
       console.log(result);
   }).submit();
});
```

and [json_encode()](http://www.php.net/json_encode) the array to be returned in PHP, like:

```
...
$arr=array('username'=>array('isEmpty'=>'required','exists'=>'username exists'),'password'=>array('isEmpty'=>'required'))
echo json_encode($arr);
```

See: [ajaxForm](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#json)

Answer (score 1):

You have to parse the array as JSON:

```
json_encode();
```

Then you can echo the result.

In JavaScript you can decode it. Because you are already using jQuery you can get the data in the array from 'result'. Access it like `result.username.isEmpty`

Answer (score 1):

Try `echo json_encode($arr);` in your upload.php.
And in your ajaxForm plugin set the option to json like below

```
 $('#submitForm').ajaxForm({
                dataType:  'json',
                success:   function(result){
                      $('#usererr').html(result['username']['isEmpty']);   
                      $('#passerr').html(result['password']['isEmpty']);
                },                  
            }).submit();
```